# I am using ASP.NET Core as backend and vue.js library as frontend but it passes null to my controller

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, vuejs3, asp.net-core-webapi

When I try to update product, the code passes null to my controller action method.

Here is my code for update product in `main.js`:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        loading: false,
        objectIndex:0,
        productModel: {
            id:1,
            name: "Product Name",
            description: "Product Description",
            value: 1.99
            },
        products: []
    },
    methods:
    {
        createProduct() {
            this.loading = true;
            axios.post('/Admin/products', this.productModel)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res.data);
                    this.products.push(res.data);
                })
                .catch(err => { console.log(err); })
                .then(() => { this.loading = false; });

        },
        updateProduct() {
            this.loading = true;
            axios.put('/Admin/products', this.productModel)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res.data);
                    this.products.splice(this.objectIndex, 1, res.data);
                })
                .catch(err => { console.log(err); })
                .then(() => {
                    this.loading = false;
                });
        },
        
        editProduct(product, index) {
            this.objectIndex = index;
            this.productModel = {
                id: product.id,
                name: product.name,
                description: product.description,
                value: product.value,
            };
            }}});
```

Here is my markup for `index.cshtml`:

```
@page
@model Shop.Ui.Pages.Admin.IndexModel
@{
}
@section scripts
    {
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@1.1.2/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/admin/main.js"></script>

}
<div id="app">
 <button v-on:click="getProducts">Get Products</button>
    <div>
        <p v-for="(product,index) in products">
            {{product.id}} - {{product.name}} - {{product.description}}
            <a @@click="editProduct(product,index)">Edit</a>
            <a @@click="deleteProduct(product.id)">Remove</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <input v-model="productModel.name"/> 
        <input v-model="productModel.description" />
        <input v-model.number="productModel.value" />
        <button @@click="createProduct" v-if="!productModel.id">Create Product</button>
        <button @@click="updateProduct" v-else>Update Product</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my code for the controller action method:

```
[HttpPut("products")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateProduct([FromBody]UpdateProduct.Request request) 
    => Ok(await new UpdateProduct(_ctx).Do(request));
```

Vue.js is passing null to my controller action method `UpdateProduct`.

I tried to pass request object as parameter to `UpdateProduct` action method using Vue.js, but when I run the application, it is null.

I am getting the following errors in the server logs:

```
An error occurred: An exception was thrown while attempting to evaluate the LINQ query parameter expression 'value(Shop.Application.ProductsAdmin.UpdateProduct+<>c__DisplayClass2_0).request.Id'. See the inner exception for more information.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.ApplicationException: An error occurred while updating the product.

at Shop.Application.ProductsAdmin.UpdateProduct.Do(Request request) in D:\pratice\Shop.Ui\Shop.Application\ProductsAdmin\UpdateProduct.cs:line 50  
at Shop.Ui.Controllers.AdminController.UpdateProduct(Request request) in D:\pratice\Shop.Ui\Shop.Ui\Controllers\AdminController.cs:line 31
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)  
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)  
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)  
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()  
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---  
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)  
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)  
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)  
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()  
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---  
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)  
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)  
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)  
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)  
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: it can become null when the actual type being received doesn't match the expected type.  The type seen after `[FromBody]` needs to match the type of productModel.